# How do I set "Parameter content type" using Swashbuckle?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-2.2

My swagger ui shows "Parameter content type" with various entries: `"application/json-patch+json"`, `"text/json"`, `"application/json"`, and `"application/*+json"`.

I only want `"application/json"`.

There's a [similar](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/1270) unsolved issue on the repo, which uses this visual (older ui, but same idea):

[image]

Is there some way to set this?

`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` version `4.0.1`
`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters` version `4.5.5`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use the `[Produces]` and `[Consumes]` attributes. Swashbuckle (and others, like NSwag) will convert them into the appropriate Swagger documentation.

The `[Consumes]` attribute's constructor's first parameter is `String contentType`:

```cs
public ConsumesAttribute ( string contentType, params string[] otherContentTypes );
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.consumesattribute.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ConsumesAttribute__ctor_System_String_System_String___

Like so:

```cs
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllBase
{
    [HttpPost( "/foo/bar" )]
    [Consumes( MediaTypeNames.Application.Json )] // "application/json"
    [Produces( typeof(MyResponseDto) ) ]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post( [FromBody] MyRequestDto dto )
    {
        // 
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a global way to set this?

Comment: @liang have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36628866/537842