# Import OpenAPI 2.0 Postman collection and all POST request bodies are displayed as x-www-form-urlencoded, instead of raw JSON

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, postman, swashbuckle

### What I am using?

**.NET Framework 4.8**
Postman Version 7.19.1
Swashbuckle 5.6.0, nugget package

---

### Problem?

I have a big API using Swagger (Swashbuckle) and I want to import the Open API schema to Postman as a collection.
After going on `{myUrl}/swagger/docs/v1` and pasting the schema in Postman I've noticed that all my Post requests were 'broken'. When going to `Body` it was shown as `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, not as raw `JSON` body.

[image]

Instead, it looks like this:

[image]

My schema:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "v1",
        "title": "My API"
    },
    "host": "localhost:51209",
    "schemes": [
        "http"
    ],
    "paths": { },
    "definitions": { }
}
```

`paths` and `definitions` are not empty, they contain a lot of API calls, that's why I will pick just one POST method from them because all are with the same issue.

Here is one example of `paths` object and the property `"consumes"` in it:

```
"/api/MyController/MyMethod": {
        "consumes": [
            "application/json",
            "text/json",
            "application/xml",
            "text/xml",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]
}
```

As it seems the problem is in the `consumes` object property that has an array of strings as values and one of them is `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

I have no 'special' attributes above my action or controller in the .NET Web API.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("MyMethod")]
public IHttpActionResult MyMethod(List<JobHeaderInputModel> jobHeaderList)
```

I know there is a `Consumes` attribute for ASP Net Core, but I am on .NET Framework.

Comment: You probably need to add or change annotations so that the generated `consumes` does not include `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This media type is not used with `in: body` parameters anyway.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I thought, as far as I know, there are attributes available for swagger, but couldn't find any that are responsible for that. That is exactly my question and I am not sure what attribute I have to put.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set “Parameter content type” using Swashbuckle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55978068/113116)

Comment: It's for ASP .NET Core 2.2, can't find the right one for .NET Framework 4.8. But actually it's exactly what I am searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

I saw this amazing [article](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/08/04/swashbuckle-pro-tips-for-aspnet-web-api-part-1/) and implemented the solution there:

Created a custom attribute:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class SwaggerConsumesAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SwaggerConsumesAttribute(params string[] contentTypes)
    {
        this.ContentTypes = contentTypes;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ContentTypes { get; }
}
```

After that create an `OperationFilter` class for Swagger:

```cs
public class ConsumesOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        var attribute = apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<SwaggerConsumesAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
        if (attribute == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        operation.consumes.Clear();
        operation.consumes = attribute.ContentTypes.ToList();
    }
}
```

And finally, just register the `OperationFilter` in `SwaggerConfig.cs` as follows:

```cs
c.OperationFilter<ConsumesOperationFilter>();
```