# Why is SwaggerGen generating content type named as "application/*+json"

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have an application that uses `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3"`.

The implementation in startup is straight forward, the services inject the generator:
`services.AddSwaggerGen();`

And the app builder activates swagger in standard manner:
`app.UseSwagger();`

Why is it then that I find "application/*+json" as content type for certain post operations in the definition?. This is an issue as it breaks certain services that re-use the openapi definition.

Is there any known way of avoiding this and using plain "application/json" content type in the definition?.

Thanks,

Comment: [Does `[Consumes( MediaTypeNames.Application.Json )]` useful to you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978068/how-do-i-set-parameter-content-type-using-swashbuckle)

Comment: Hello Json, many thanks for your suggestion. At first I thought the content-types were wrong, while they were just a fallback list of formats. That attribute setting narrows down the content-types to the ones specified.

Answer (score 1):

If we just want use plain `application/json` content type, you can add attribute like : `[Consumes( MediaTypeNames.Application.Json )]`. If we want to use other plain, we can click the drop-down box.

**Sample code:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Consumes(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json )]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
{
     
}
```